# jQuery/Javascript method to show/hide multiple fields upon selection with common fields to multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with multiple fields, some of which only show when a certain selection is made, that is easy enough to do but where I am struggling is when I have common fields which much show on different selections.

I now I can make duplicate fields with unique classes or id's but that feels like the wrong way to do it. Any help will be greatly appreciated and if this has been asked before I am genuinely sorry, I did search with no luck.

Example code as follows:

```js
$('#order_type').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "plates_stepped") {
        $(".stepped").show("slow");
      } else {
        $("#plate_qty").val(0);
        $("#plate_thickness").val(0);
        $("#plate_wrong_reading").val(0);
        $("#plate_right_reading").val(0);
        $(".stepped").hide("slow");
      };
      if ($(this).val() === "plates_not_stepped") {
        $(".not_stepped").show("slow");
        $(".common_plates").show("slow");
      } else {
        $(".not_stepped").val(0);
        $(".not_stepped").hide("slow");
        $(".common_plates").hide("slow");
      };
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="order_type" class="col-3 col-form-label">What would you like us to provide?</label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="order_type" required>
                        <option value="0">Please select...</option>
                        <option value="plates_stepped">Direct - Plates (I have stepped)</option>
                        <option value="plates_not_stepped">Direct - Plates (Step for me)</option>
                        <option value="plates_remake">Direct - Plates Remake</option>
                        <option value="proof_only">Proof Only</option>
                        <option value="acme_traditional">Acme Traditional</option>
                    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row stepped common_plates" style="display: none;">
  <label for="plate_qty" class="col-3 col-form-label">Total Plates To Make</label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="4" id="plate_qty" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group radio-field is-required stepped common_plates" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Plates Thickness?</label>
  <div class="radio custom-radio form-check-inline col-9">
    <input checked="checked" name="plate_thickness" value="1" type="radio" id="45th">
    <label for="45th">1.14mm - 45th.</label>
    <input name="plate_thickness" value="2" type="radio" id="67th">
    <label for="67th">1.70mm - 67th.</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group radio-field is-required stepped common_plates" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Mirror Plates?</label>
  <div class="radio custom-radio form-check-inline col-9">
    <input checked="checked" name="plate_reading" value="1" type="radio" id="plate_right_reading">
    <label for="plate_right_reading">Right reading</label>
    <input name="plate_reading" value="2" type="radio" id="plate_wrong_reading">
    <label for="plate_wrong_reading">Wrong Reading</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row not_stepped" style="display: none;">
  <label for="teeth_qty" class="col-3 col-form-label">Teeth quantity</label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="92" id="teeth_qty" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group radio-field is-required not_stepped" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Gear Type</label>
  <div class="radio custom-radio form-check-inline col-9">
    <input checked="checked" name="gear_type" value="1" type="radio" id="1_8cp">
    <label for="1_8cp">1/8CP</label>
    <input name="gear_type" value="2" type="radio" id="31dp">
    <label for="31dp">32 DP</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain, how you want to display? Like if someone selects first option then which fields should be displayed

Comment: Its unclear. Elaborate on which field should be visible on what selection.

Comment: my bad, so if the user selects the first option: value="plates_stepped" then it should show only the first 3 fields, if the user selects the second option: value="plates_not_stepped" then all fields should show (that are listed above) I have many more fields and most are unique to the selection but some selections have common fields which must show so I just need to know how to set it up so that some fields can be common to more that 1 select option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pseudo code that might help you. So assign a common class to each of your `div`. I have assigned `plates-option` as a common class.

Now, each of this `div` should also have a class name, same as the `option` values (*check the HTML*). Once, you do this things, it becomes easier to show/hide the `div`'s based on the value selected from the drop-down.

```js
$('#order_type').change(function() {
  $("div.plates-options").hide();
  $("div." + $(this).val()).show();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#order_type').trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="order_type" class="col-3 col-form-label">What would you like us to provide?</label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="order_type" required>
<option value="0">Please select...</option>
<option value="plates_stepped">Direct - Plates (I have stepped)</option>
<option value="plates_not_stepped">Direct - Plates (Step for me)</option>
<option value="plates_remake">Direct - Plates Remake</option>
<option value="proof_only">Proof Only</option>
<option value="acme_traditional">Acme Traditional</option>
</select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group plates-options row plates_stepped common_plates">
  plates_stepped & common plates
</div>
<div class="form-group plates-options row plates_not_stepped common_plates">
  plates_not_stepped & common plates
</div>
<div class="form-group plates-options row plates_remake">
  plates_remake
</div>
<div class="form-group plates-options row proof_only">
  proof_only
</div>
<div class="form-group plates-options row acme_traditional common_plates">
  acme_traditional & common plates
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you and need to change condition as per requirement:

```js
$('#order_type').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "plates_stepped") {
    $(".not_stepped").val(0);
    $(".not_stepped").hide("slow");
    $(".common_plates").hide("slow");
    $(".stepped").show("slow");
  } else if ($(this).val() === "plates_not_stepped") {
    $("#plate_qty").val(0);
    $("#plate_thickness").val(0);
    $("#plate_wrong_reading").val(0);
    $("#plate_right_reading").val(0);
    $(".stepped").hide("slow");
    $(".not_stepped").show("slow");
    $(".common_plates").show("slow");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="order_type" class="col-3 col-form-label">What would you like us to provide?</label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="order_type" required>
                            <option value="0">Please select...</option>
                            <option value="plates_stepped">Direct - Plates (I have stepped)</option>
                            <option value="plates_not_stepped">Direct - Plates (Step for me)</option>
                            <option value="plates_remake">Direct - Plates Remake</option>
                            <option value="proof_only">Proof Only</option>
                            <option value="acme_traditional">Acme Traditional</option>
                        </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row stepped common_plates" style="display: none;">
  <label for="plate_qty" class="col-3 col-form-label">Total Plates To Make</label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="4" id="plate_qty" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group radio-field is-required stepped common_plates" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Plates Thickness?</label>
  <div class="radio custom-radio form-check-inline col-9">
    <input checked="checked" name="plate_thickness" value="1" type="radio" id="45th">
    <label for="45th">1.14mm - 45th.</label>
    <input name="plate_thickness" value="2" type="radio" id="67th">
    <label for="67th">1.70mm - 67th.</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group radio-field is-required stepped common_plates" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Mirror Plates?</label>
  <div class="radio custom-radio form-check-inline col-9">
    <input checked="checked" name="plate_reading" value="1" type="radio" id="plate_right_reading">
    <label for="plate_right_reading">Right reading</label>
    <input name="plate_reading" value="2" type="radio" id="plate_wrong_reading">
    <label for="plate_wrong_reading">Wrong Reading</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row not_stepped" style="display: none;">
  <label for="teeth_qty" class="col-3 col-form-label">Teeth quantity</label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="92" id="teeth_qty" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group radio-field is-required not_stepped" style="display: none;">
  <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Gear Type</label>
  <div class="radio custom-radio form-check-inline col-9">
    <input checked="checked" name="gear_type" value="1" type="radio" id="1_8cp">
    <label for="1_8cp">1/8CP</label>
    <input name="gear_type" value="2" type="radio" id="31dp">
    <label for="31dp">32 DP</label>
  </div>
</div>
```